# Creating a Adjustment gives me a TX Error when releasing

Tags: acumatica

I am creating an adjustment during the release of a receipt.

```
public void CreateAdjustment()
        {

            try
            {
                INAdjustmentEntry iNAdjustmentEntryEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INAdjustmentEntry>();
                INRegister iNRegister = new INRegister();

                iNRegister = iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.adjustment.Insert();
                iNRegister.Status = INDocStatus.Balanced;
                iNRegister.ExtRefNbr = Base.CurrentDocument.Current.ExtRefNbr == null ? " " : Base.CurrentDocument.Current.ExtRefNbr;
                iNRegister.TranDesc = Base.CurrentDocument.Current.TranDesc == null ? " " : Base.CurrentDocument.Current.TranDesc;
                iNRegister.Hold = false;

                INSetup iNSetup = PXSelect<INSetup>.Select(Base);
                INSetupExt iNSetupExt = iNSetup.GetExtension<INSetupExt>();

                iNRegister = iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.adjustment.Update(iNRegister);
                iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.adjustment.Current = iNRegister;

                iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.adjustment.SetValueExt<INRegisterExt.usrReasonCode>(iNRegister, iNSetupExt.UsrAutoGenAdjustmentFromAdjustments);
                // iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.Save.PressButton();

                foreach (INTran item in Base.transactions.Select())
                {
                    INTran iNTran = iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.transactions.Insert();

                    iNTran.InventoryID = item.InventoryID;

                    iNTran.ReasonCode = iNSetupExt.UsrAutoGenAdjustmentFromAdjustments;
                    iNTran.LocationID = item.LocationID;
                    iNTran.SiteID = item.SiteID;

                    iNTran.Qty = 0;
                    var rowExt = Base.transactions.Cache.GetExtension<INTranExt>(item);
                    if (rowExt.UsrNewUnitCost == null)
                    {
                        rowExt.UsrNewUnitCost = 0;
                    }

                    iNTran.TranCost = item.Qty * (rowExt.UsrNewUnitCost - item.UnitCost);
                    iNTran.UnitCost = item.UnitCost;

                    iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.transactions.Update(iNTran);
                }

                iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.Save.PressButton();
                iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.release.PressButton();
                         
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                PXTrace.WriteError("JVD2StepTransfersWithExtraAdjustments CreateAdjustment: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The save works but when I press the release at the end I get the following error:

[image]

I think the document needs to do a background process so that it knows its in a balanced state but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Try to replace this two lines 
  INRegister iNRegister = new INRegister(); 
  iNRegister = iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.adjustment.Insert(); 
with 
  iNRegister = iNAdjustmentEntryEntry.adjustment.Insert(new INRegister());

Answer (score 0):

I would not set the workflow status manually. I have inserted INAdjustments fine in the past. The difference between your code and mine is that I complete the document, then remove it from hold, save, and release.

```
//insert document and lines
register.Hold = false;
register = adjGraph.adjustment.Update(register);
adjGraph.Save.Press();
adjGraph.release.Press();
```